# How to add a column to a List<> at run run time

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0

```
while (sqlreader.Read())
{
   missionIdList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(sqlreader[0].ToString()));
}
```

In the above code snippet, missionIdList is of type `List<long>` and sqlreader returns n number of rows with 3 columns.

How can i add a fourth column(of type uniqueidentifier - .NET Guid) whose values are coming from a .NET variable to the list.

I want to get 3 columns from the sqlreader, add a fourth column for each row returned and end up with missionIdList `List<>` of 4 columns.

ALSO note that all columns returned by sqlreader are integers but the fourth column i want to add is a .NET Guid

Comment: Did you try to add this column in your sql query?

Comment: @SonerGönül, that column is not in the database, its got from a .NET variable.

Comment: List of *what* you want to have?

Comment: If you define List<long> you cannot put a Guid, why not strings?

Comment: Do not understand question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to use anonymous types.
Your code should look like this.

```
var missionIdList = new List<object>();

while (sqlreader.Read())
{
   var obj = new { c1 = Convert.ToInt32(sqlreader[0].ToString()), 
                   c2 = Convert.ToInt32(sqlreader[1].ToString()),
                   c3 = Convert.ToInt32(sqlreader[2].ToString()),
                   uid = uid };
   missionIdList.Add(obj);
}
```

But if you do not need to add it from runtime (because you know what you are going to receive), you just build you classes before use and add them to your list typed. Which is the correct and preferred way.

Comment: It would likely be a lot better to create a real class instead of an anonymous class. Otherwise unless you use the `dynamic` keyword you are not going to be able to get the objects out of the list.